# How to print to one line from multiple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a text based game but am very new to programming, I want to do something like

```
from time import sleep
print('first part' sleep(1)'second part')
```

but that obviously does not work so I was wondering if I could print one part of the line, wait, and then print the second part to the same line but from different lines so that it would work

Answer (score 4):

Sure, this is possible, you'll just have to send some options to `print()`:

```
from time import sleep
print("This is the first part. ", end='', flush=True)
sleep(1)
print("This is the second part.")
```

`end=''` means that the `print` function doesn't append a newline `\n` onto the end of what it's printing. `flush=True` means the buffer is flushed right away, so it's immediately printed. Experiment with removing that part and see what happens.

Comment: ok thanks, if I wanted to add more than two, I'd do the same thing over and over until the last one, right?

Answer (score 0):

Quick Function to do this. You just have to put your strings into a list.

```
import time

def PrintWithPauses(lists):
    for x in range(len(lists)):
        if x == len(lists):
            print(lists[x])
        else:
            print(lists[x], end='', flush=True)
            time.sleep(1)
```

So if you had a list like this:

```
myList = ['hello world! ', 'StackOverflow ', 'bob ']
```

and ran:

```
PrintWithPauses(myList)
```

Your output would be:

```
hello world!
```

Pause 1 second

```
hello world! StackOverflow
```

Pause 1 second

```
hello world! StackOverflow bob
```